# Linux: find and differentiate files with partial matches in filenames

Tags: linux, find, filenames

I have filenames that have partial matches, like below:
ABC10D.txt
C10D.txt

I am trying to do the following.

```
for file in C10D ABC10D
do
x=find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$file*"
echo $x
{do something to }
done
```

"do something" is processing the file using a shell script. The folder contains many such files with the partial match "C10D". Because of the partial match, the pattern "C10D" also finds files ABC10D.txt. How can I avoid this. I am sure there probably is a easy solution to this, but have been struggling for few hrs. now. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unless you have an * on BOTH sides of $file ABC10D.txt should **not** match ...

Comment: Had an error in my previous post. Just corrected that. I am using "$file" as the pattern. If I use * on either or both ends, I don't get anything. Wierd

Comment: Please ignore previous comment. Had an error in my main post previously. Just corrected that. I was using * on both sides of "$file" like you pointed. Thanks. Silly mistake. Actually had a grep command built into the script which was complicating affairs. But your comment helped correct the problem. Thanks.